# Is it possible to search through a very large excel file that includes latitude and longitudes and return rows within a certain radius? (Java)

Tags: java, excel, math, geographic-distance

I have a very large excel sheet (about 30,000+) records of house prices and their location (a latitude and longitude value). At the moment I can parse parts of the excel sheet into the console of Eclipse using Apache POI. However is it possible to return only certain rows and their house prices if they were within a radius of x KM of a given latitude and longitude by a user?

I'm lead to believe the haversine formula could be used to calculate something like this but I've hit a brick wall as to how I would begin implementing that into a program like this.

```
public class ExcelReader {

    public static final String SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH = "./LatLongPrice.xlsx";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));

        // Retrieving the number of sheets in the Workbook
        System.out.println("Workbook has " + workbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");




        // obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
        Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();
        System.out.println("Retrieving Sheets using Iterator");
        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
            System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }



        // Getting the Sheet at index zero
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        // Obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
        System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Iteratating over the columns of the current row
           Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        });

        // Closing the workbook
        workbook.close();
    }
```

Comment: Why are they not in a database? It seems Excel is more popular today than it was in the 90's.

Comment: Would a table of 30,000+ rows not be quite large for a simple MySQL database? Would parsing through that be more exhausting on the application than the excel which it seems to parse through with relative ease?

Comment: Database tables can have millions of rows. They were created for that purpose. I'd put 'em in a Postgres DB and use PostGIS to query directly for the location. No use in reinventing the wheel after all.

Comment: Ok, Kayman I'll give that a go thank you!

Comment: @pnuts please see: Why do I have nothing better to do than leaving useless comments on reasonable questions?

Comment: @pnuts Can you show me where charlie has used this phrase?

Comment: @pnuts well, is it possible?

Comment: @Charlie, it is not clear where your "brick wall" is. Do you know in which columns lies the Lat/Long data? Do you know how to parse a numerical value from a given cell (row + column)? Do you know how to implement the haversine in Java?